# How to specify the type of an anonymous type while using a generic type

Tags: c#, .net, linq, anonymous-types, typeinitializeexception

The title is pretty confusing. I will try to explain with an example. Consider the code below:

```
String[] str={"Apple","Banana","Cherry","Orange"};
var anoCollection=from e in str select new
                                         {
                                          ch=e[0],
                                          length=e.Length
                                         }
dataGridView.DataSource=anoCollection.ToList(); //TypeInitializationException
```

I feel that I need to mention the type in above case for the `ToList<T>()` method. But how can I mention an anonymous type here?

Comment: @TimSchmelter actually, in many cases the `.ToList()` version would be preferable, especially in winforms - it wants an `IList`, and a *sequence* will not work

Comment: TypeInitializationException comes with an InnerException; what does *that* say? That tells you what the actual problem was.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud that is certainly a related topic, but I don't think that addresses the question here

Comment: @MarcGravell, duly noted, I will remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *never* possible to mention an anonymous type directly, but you should not need to. Generic type inference means that you don't need to specify the `<T>` in `.ToList<T>()` - the compiler will automatically inject the invented type.

There are only a few ways to refer to an anonymous type:

- via `someObj.GetType()`, where `someObj` is an instance of an anonymous type
- via generics, as a `T`, by calling a generic method via generic type inference (as in `ToList()`)
- various other usages of reflection, pulling in the `T` via `GetGenericTypeParameters()`

Answer (score 0):

This may be not what you are asking for, but if you later want to use the DataBoundItem for a row, you can do it this way:

```
var item = TypeExtensions.CastByPrototype(row.DataBoundItem, new { ch = 'a', length = 0});
//you can use item.ch and item.length here
Trace.WriteLine(item.ch);
```

with the support of this method:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static T CastByPrototype<T>(object obj, T prototype)
    {
        return (T)obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make this a bit more readable by making it an extension method and naming it `CastToTypeOf`. So all this reads: `row.DataBoundItem.CastToTypeOf(new { ch = 'a', length = 0 })`.